# How to parse this structure: "name[arg,arg]" with scala combinator parsers?

Tags: parsing, scala, parser-combinators

I have several strings like these:

```
name[arg,arg,arg]
name[arg,arg]
name[arg]
name
```

I wanted to parse it with scala combinator parsers, and this is the best that I managed to get:

```
object TaskDepParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def name: Parser[String] = "[^\\[\\],]+".r
  def expr: Parser[(String, Option[List[String]])] = 
    name ^^ { a => (a, None) } |
    name ~ "[" ~ repsep(name, ",") ~ "]" ^^ { case name~_~args~_ => (name, Some(args)) }
}
```

It works on `name`, but fails to work on `name[arg]` - says `string matching regex`\z' expected but `[' found`. Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: I think it might work if you flip it around...I think name is getting sucked up by the first rule, and then you get a failure on input?

Comment: @TonyK. - Wow, stupid me. You are right, flipping it worked. You can post that as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@TonyK has already given the answer in his comment. But I wanna suggest that Scala parser combinators can already parse optional values:

```
object TaskDepParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def name: Parser[String] = """[^\[\],]+""".r
  def expr: Parser[(String, Option[List[String]])] =
    name ~ opt("[" ~> repsep(name, ",") <~ "]") ^^ { case name ~ args => (name, args) }
}
```

With `~>` and `<~` it is possible to keep only left or right result to avoid unnecessary patter matching in `^^`. Furthermore I would use triple quotes for strings to avoid lots of escaping.

Answer (score 2):

I think it might work if you flip it around...Name is getting sucked up by the first rule, and then you get a failure on input.